# Accessing guest OS (Ubuntu)s locally hosted sites by host OS (OS X)

Tags: vmware-fusion, apache-http-server

I think the title explains fairly well what I want to do, but here's some additional info:

Guest OS (Ubuntu)s configuration, running in VMWare Fusion:
I have 3 virtual sites hosted by Apache2, which are accessed using the following lines from my /etc/hosts on Ubuntu:

```
127.0.0.1 siteA.localhost

127.0.0.2 siteB.localhost

127.0.0.3 siteC.localhost
```

However, I want my host OS (OS X) to be able to access these as well.

Ubuntu's IP is 172.16.47.132.

When I visit that IP in my OS X browser it just see a typical "Index Of /" page with no clickable folders, so it seems like I'm able to reach the webserver, but not the sites.

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve the issue using the following steps:

1. Open 
   `/etc/rc.local`
2. Add one line for each virtual NIC I want to create, an example:

   `ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.160.0.255`
3. Edit virtual hosts in apache2 to also listen to the newly created virtual NICs. Example:

   `< VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80 192.168.0.2:80 >`
4. Restart Ubuntu, and everything worked just fine.

Apparently there's a bug in Ubuntu 11.10 which makes the entries in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file not work as they should, so the methods related to that file did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

127.x.x.x are localhost IP-numbers, so when you access them you'll end up at your own computer (your host OS presumably has an "Index of /" displaying on its web server)

What you need to do to access the web server from another host is use the "real" IP number of the guest (presumably a 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x IP since it's a local VM), not the localhost one. That also means that you need to make Apache bind to real IPs instead of the localhost ones for their virtual sites.

Comment: Well, the real IP is in this case 172.16.47.132, which is the one I'm visiting when I get the "Index of /" page on my host OS (my host OS has it's own webserver on a different address). 

By binding real IPs do you mean adding for example <VirtualHost 172....> to the config sites? If that's the case, can I bind more than the one IP my Ubuntu has assigned to it?

Comment: @DevEight Yes, if you want to VirtualHost by IP, you need to  add more IP numbers, a fairly simple procedure; http://adventuresinswitching.blogspot.com/2008/05/setup-multiple-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu.html